# IOS - CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am getting the erro below when i try to call the custom API that i have, i am using alamofire

```
let API_URL = "https://localhost:5001/api"

func registerNewUser(parameters: Parameters) {

        let urlString = API_URL + "/register/PostTest"
        let url = URL.init(string: urlString)

        print("URL: \(url!)")

        Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).debugLog().responseJSON{ //--> point of failure
            response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                print("Success! the request to the API is successful")

                let userJson : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

                print(userJson)

            } else {
                print("Error \(response.result.error!)")
            }
        }
    }


info.plist file
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
            <dict>
                <key>https://localhost</key>
                <dict>
                    <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                    <true/>
                    <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
                    <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                    <true/>
                    <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
                    <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                    <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```

The Error is:

> CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
>       class = inet;
>       "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
>       ptcl = htps;
>       "r_Attributes" = 1;
>       sdmn = localhost;
>       srvr = localhost;
>       sync = syna;
>   }

Comment: What's the actual issue? This is just log spew from the system when Alamofire attempts to lookup credentials and they don't exist.

Comment: Thats the issue, i try to do an API request and it fails

Comment: In what way does it fail? You need to be specific about what your issue is here. As best I can tell the server is prompting your app for credentials which you haven't provided. Is that what you expected?

Comment: @JonShier thank you for your responce, i have checked the requset using postman and it's working. i have update the question to show the point of failure

Comment: Sorry, there's still not enough information to tell what's wrong. How is the request failing? What are you getting and what are you expecting?